# laravel ajax is not working , it seen fail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to insert data from register form by ajax.
but I see `ajax failed` in my console log.
I can't understand what is problem ?
here is my js :

```
$('#Personal_Information').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : 'json',
            url: "{{url('all/update-profile')}}", 
            data: {csrf_token:"{{csrf_token()}}", data: form_data}
        }).done( function(data){
            console.log('Ajax was Successful!')
            console.log(data)
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log('Ajax Failed')
        });
```

here is my route :

```
Route::get('/update-profile', 'personalinformation@redirectupdatepage')->name('/all.update-profile');
Route::post('/all/update-profile', 'personalinformation@store');
```

my controller's code :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $modal = User::create($request->all());
    return $modal;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you change your `.fail(function())` callback to `.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error))`? Then console.log `xhr.responseText` so we can know the actual error :)

Comment: "Internal Server Error" in my console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token field name must be _token,
Update your code, this line.

```
 data: { _token:"{{csrf_token()}}", data: form_data},
```

Best solution is add meta tag and header.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<script>

   $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

</script>
```

Update Your Controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $modal = User::create($request->get('data'));
    return $modal;
}
```

Comment: thanks ... its improvement answer ..... i see now "Internal Server Error" in my console.log

Comment: You have to update your controller store method like above